# Registering a filter in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

From what I have read, a filter can be registered either by annotating it with `@Component` or by registering it in a `FilterRegistrationBean`.  However, I cannot seem to do with just with `@Component`.

The following code works

```
//@Component
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("*** Loading authFilter");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final @NonNull HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, final @NonNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("*** calling filter");
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        System.out.println("*** return from filter");
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<AuthFilter> filter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean<AuthFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        bean.setFilter(this);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

However, if I comment out the `FilterRegistrationBean` method and uncomment the `@Component` annotation, I get the following stack trace at start-up

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-21T23:00:52.856Z","level":"WARN","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext","thread_name":"main","nexusService":"skeleton-Micro-service"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-21T23:00:52.868Z","level":"INFO","message":" 
 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener","thread_name":"main","nexusService":"skeleton-Micro-service"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-21T23:00:52.897Z","level":"ERROR","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","nexusService":"skeleton-Micro-service","stack_trace":"org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) 
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:447) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1356) 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1345) 
    at com.torchai.service.skeleton.NexusSkeletonServiceApplication.main(NexusSkeletonServiceApplication.java:10) 
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:455) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:204) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) 
    ... 8 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) 
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) 
    ... 13 common frames omitted 
"}
```

I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong.  If I don't need to specify the order, url or any properties on the `FilterRegistrationBean`, is it still required?

## Update

The filter is in package `com.torchai.service.filter;` and on my application, class, I have @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.torchai.service"}).  My @PostConstruct method is getting called.  So the class is definitely getting loaded

Comment: Not by annotating `@Component`, but by registering it as a Spring bean by any method (including `@Import` and `@Bean`). Most likely your `@Component` isn't getting scanned for whatever reason.

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's the case.  The filter is in package `com.torchai.service.filter;` and on my application, class, I have `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.torchai.service"})`.  But even if it had something to do with that, if it didn't find the class, then it just wouldn't load the filter.  I wouldn't get a stacktrace because of it.  Also, my `@PostConstruct` method is getting called

Comment: i think you should define `FilterRegistrationBean` in seperate class, since current class `AuthFilter` is the class to be registered.

Comment: Yes, defining `FilterRegistrationBean` in a separate class seems to work as well, but my question is, do I need it?  Why am I getting an exception when the service starts when I just annotate my filter with `@Component`.  I shouldn't need to use `FilterRegistrationBean` if I don't need to update the order, url or other properties.